# How to replace domain name of all email

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql, oracle10g, plsqldeveloper

I am trying to replace the ending of any email with a specific email domain.The procedure will be passed two strings: First is the original domain name that is to be replaced; and Second the new domain name that will be replacing the original (in that order). For example, if the procedure is passed the strings "sadme.com” and "happyme.com", every e-mail in the database with "sadme.com" as their domain name will be changed to "happyme.com" as their domain name

Examples:

```
Before                     After
-------------------------- ---------------------------
ExampleEmail@yahoo.com     ExampleEmail@gmail.com
SecondExample@hotmail.com  SecondExample@gmail.com
```

This is what i have but im getting an error

```
          Create Procedure PR_Q3
    (P_OldDomain Varchar2,P_NewDomain Varchar2)
    As
      Cursor C_Domains IS Select Email_Address


       From Broker 
                     where Email_Address =  '%@'||P_OldDomain;
               V_OldDomain Varchar2(50);       
          Begin
          Open C_Domains;
          Fetch C_Domains INTO V_OldDomain;
          While C_Domains%Found loop
                if C_Domains = '%@'||P_OldDomain Then
                    Update Broker
                    Set Email_Address = P_NewDomain
                    Where Email_Address = V_OldDomain;
              End if;      
          Fetch C_Domains into P_NewDomain;
          End Loop;
  Close C_Domains;
End PR_Q3;
/
Show Errors;
```

im getting the errors:

LINE/COL ERROR

---

2/29     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following:

```
     := . ) , @ % default character
     The symbol ":=" was substituted for "(" to continue.
```

2/61     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following:

```
     := . ) , @ % default character
     The symbol ":=" was substituted for "(" to continue.
```

Also i tried taking out the varchar2(50) and just put Varchar2 and it gives me error:

```
 PLS-00403: expression 'P_NewDomain' cannot be used as an INTO-target of a SELECT/FETCH statement
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Starting at position 1, replace the second set of characters that aren't `'@'` with `bananas.com`:

```
regexp_replace(email, '[^@]+', 'bananas.com', 1, 2)
```

or just replace everything from `'@'` onwards with `@bananas.com`:

```
regexp_replace(email, '@.+*','@bananas.com')
```

Comment: would this work in a procedure that has a cursor too?

Comment: I don't see why not, it's just SQL.

Answer (score 1):

I ran the following on an Oracle 10 DB. Hopefully this is what you need:

```
WITH
    sampledata AS
        (SELECT 'finger@doctors.com' AS eaddress FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'toe.on.foon@real.goofy.org' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'facenose@skeleton.usa' FROM DUAL)
SELECT eaddress
     , REGEXP_REPLACE (eaddress, '^(.+@).+(\..+$)', '\1gmail\2') t
  FROM sampledata;

eaddress                     t
finger@doctors.com          finger@gmail.com
toe.on.foon@real.goofy.org  toe.on.foon@gmail.org
facenose@skeleton.usa       facenose@gmail.usa
```

The parenthesis are groupings that can be referenced in the replacement string with \1 \2 \3 ...

```
"^"        - anchor to start of string
"(.+@)"    - take everything up to '@', we will reference this as \1
".+"       - any number of characters following the @ sign
"+(\..+$)" - everything followed by the last period, anchored to the end of the string
we will reference this with \2

"\1gmail\2" - take the first reference, follow it with "gmail", then follow that 
with the second reference
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a cursor for this as an UPDATE will suffice (unless there is more to the story you are leaving out).  Remember, row by row = slow by slow!  Plus you have some syntax errors in your create procedure code.  This update selects only the rows that match your old domain criteria, and replaces with the new domain passed in.

```
Create or replace Procedure PR_Q3(P_OldDomain varchar2, P_NewDomain Varchar2)
As
BEGIN
  UPDATE Broker
    Set Email_Address = regexp_replace(Email_Address, '^(.*@.*)'||P_OldDomain, '\1'||P_NewDomain)
    WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(Email_Address, '.*@.*'||P_OldDomain);
  COMMIT;
End PR_Q3;
```

Don't forget to add the exception handling, I'll leave that to you.

Comment: i need at least one cursor in it, any way i can do it with the cursor and still use the way you wrote it?